# Javascript Getters and Setters on class itself

Tags: javascript, class, setter, getter, self

When declaring a js class we can define the getters and setters for properties of that class like so:

```
class Foo{

    get bar(){
        return 'foo-bar';
    }

    set bar(n){
        this.baz = n * 10;
    }

}

let foo = new Foo();

console.log(foo.bar) //foo-bar

foo.bar = 7;
console.log(foo.baz) //70
```

What I was wondering is, how would I define getters and setters on **the class itself**?
So that for example foo = 7 would trigger a block of code and console.log(foo) would print 'foo-bar'.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters

Comment: One question: why?

Comment: When you assign to a variable, the variable's old value is totally ignored, it doesn't get a chance to intercept.

Comment: @AndrewLi I'd like to create classes of which instances have operational logic. E.g. vector2A += vector2B, as far as I'm aware I'll need getters and setters to achieve this, unless js has another defined way of doing this.

Comment: @Jrs.b Javascript doesn't have operator overloading, so you can't redefine `+=` to call your methods. Getters and setters won't help with that.

Comment: You can write `vector2A.add(vector2B)`, and then the getter will be used to find `vector2S.add`.

Comment: @Barmar I guess that is a good substitute, even though that's what I was trying to avoid. Hopefully js will support such definitions in the future.

Comment: please mark answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

```
foo = 7;
```

Will re-assign `foo` to `7`.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I assumed there to be a possibility since foo.bar = 7 doesn't assign 7 to foo.bar either.

Comment: @Jrs.b that made no sense... why would `foo.bar = 7` assign 7 to `foo.bar`? Why would assigning `foo` *not change `foo`*?

Comment: @Jrs.b That's because it's going through the object when it accesses the property `bar`. The object can redirect it to the getter/setter.

Comment: @Jrs.b I suppose you could try [defining a "foo" property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) on `window`. I wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: @mpen That wouldn't help if `foo` is a local variable.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `foo =` means you are assigning a value to the variable `foo`. The best you can do is use a constructor to run some code when an instance of your class gets created.

```
class Foo{

  constructor(){
    console.log('A Foo instance has been created!');
  }

  get bar(){
    return 'foo-bar';
  }

  set bar(n){
    this.baz = n * 10;
  }

}
```

Some languages also have a `destructor` specification whenever a value is destroyed or out of scope and eventually cleaned up by a garbage collector, etc, but es6 does not provide such functionality.